# Does there exist unicode "New-Line" (Line-break), like there is unicode `space` ( )?

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, ascii, ascii-art

There are site where you can get Unicode characters, like [unicode space](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html), for example, you can copy-paste that.

For example, inside the brackets below are two different UNICODE spaces, which you can copy-paste:

U+0020: ( )

U+2001: ( )

Does there exist a Unicode new-line, which I could copy-paste?  (PLEASE NOTE, I DON'T ASK ABOUT THE CODE, like `U+000D` or whatever is considered as new line. I want the "copyable" output, like the above space (which I have put above in brackets and can be copied). So, if there is, please paste it in your answer, so I could copy it, like you copy the unicode space above from brackets. I can't explain it better.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? There are many Unicode characters that cause line breaks, such as U+000A LINE FEED, U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION, U+000C FORM FEED, U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN, U+0085 NEXT LINE, U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR, and U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR. Depending on your system, hitting the Enter key will insert U+000A or <U+000D, U+000A> automatically.

Comment: @RandomGuy32 sorry, you dont understand the question, i cant explain it better than i did.

Comment: You can copy Unicode newline to the clipboard by simply selecting the region between the period in "that." and the F in "For example".

Comment: @RaymondChen Did you try that? When I attempt what you suggest there is nothing to be copied since it is not possible to select _"the region between the period in "that." and the F in "For example""_.

Comment: Works for me. Click the mouse button immediately to the right of the period, then drag down until you are immediately to the left of the F. Then type Ctrl+C to copy.

Comment: "Does there exist a Unicode new-line which I could copy-paste?" Yes. And I showed how to do it. If you want to put it in parentheses, then go ahead: Put a ( at the end of one line and a ) at the start of the next line.

Comment: @Raymon, between this words, there is a space you see. But i give example that I wanted an alternative "unicode" spaces, that I have listed. So, the same thing I wanted with line-breaks. ok, if you can't fully get me, no problem. good luck.

Comment: Since the rendering of newline changes both the X and Y coordinate. the "space you see" extends both vertically and horizontally. It starts at the end of one line and begins at the start of the next. Maybe I'm just not understanding the question. I assume you want "a way to copy/paste a Unicode newline by selecting text between two parentheses." To do that, put a ( at the end of one line and a ) at the start of the next line. The space between them is the newline.

Comment: @RaymondChen My bad - I do get U+000D U+000A. Thx.

Comment: This reminds me of the DOS days when pressing Ctrl+G makes a beep sound. In certain cases that character would be output by the system as a certain symbol (a little full circle in this case). There were also other usually non-printable characters like the Backspace, Delete, EOF (Ctrl+Z), and ESC. Each has its visual representation of a symbol on the screen which wasn't always displayed (depends on the application). I feel the OP is asking about a similar thing that represents the 0D 0A sequence, which does exist and can be viewed in an ASCII table.

Answer (score 10):

> **Does there exist a Unicode new-line, which I could copy-paste?**

Yes, but it depends on the exact circumstances.

There are many [Unicode line-terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode). For example NEL U+0085 but these do not survive being cut & pasted into this answer's text-area input field using the web-browser Chrome.  However I can successfully copy&paste it back and forth between, for example, Notepad and Vim text editors.

Of course, neither of these applications respect the meaning of this particular character.

You can cut&paste Unicode LF U+000A between, for example, Vim and Notepad and have it be treated appropriately - but I'm sure the two applications are potentially performing some conversion during the paste operations.

The way cut&paste works is platform dependent, the above is true of MS-Windows-10 and may not be true on Android, IOS, Linux, OS/X or other platforms.